# Enable and Disable Windows Firewall Rule with WindowsFirewallHelper c#

Tags: c#, windows-firewall

Hi im using the WindowsFirewallHelper Lib from here: [WindowsFirewallHelper Git](https://github.com/falahati/WindowsFirewallHelper)

First I Create a Rule

```
 IRule rule = FirewallManager.Instance.CreateApplicationRule(
            FirewallManager.Instance.GetProfile().Type,
            ruleName,
            FirewallAction.Block,
            @"Path\App.exe"
            );
            rule.Direction = FirewallDirection.Outbound;
            FirewallManager.Instance.Rules.Add(rule);
```

After that I would like to make a Connect and Disconect Method which enables or disables this rule, but I cant find any Method for it within the lib, does anybody know how to do that?
There is only the "rule.isEnabled" field which tells if it is enabled or not.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netfw/nf-netfw-inetfwauthorizedapplication-put_enabled

Comment: lots of power shell commands [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/enable-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Answer (score 3):

Since I couldnt make it happen with the Lib: I did the following for enable and disable methods:

I created a CMD Method

```
       private static void RunCMD(string argument)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";       
        startInfo.Arguments = argument;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
```

Then I added both Other Methods:

```
   public static void Disconnect()
    {

        RunCMD(@"/C netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=""RULENAME"" new enable=no");

    }


    public static void Connect()
    {
        RunCMD(@"/C netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=""RULENAME"" new enable=yes");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:
`var myRule = FirewallManager.Instance.Rules.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == "rulename"); if (myRule != null)myRule.IsEnable = false;`